# Label Points in a circle in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide, tkz-collection

Consider the slight modification of the construction from the solution to this question: [Variables and basic arithmetics and tikz-euclide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17672/variables-and-basic-arithmetics-and-tikz-euclide)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDrawCircle[R](O,1 cm)
\def\sectors{20}
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,\sectors} {
    \tkzDefPoint({\i*360/\sectors}:1){P\i}   
    \tkzDrawSegment[color=black](O,P\i)
    \tkzLabelPoint(P\i){\i} %modified here!
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the following output:

[image]

Now my question is, if it is possible to position the labels in extension of the radial lines.

Is it possible to rotate the labels additionally corresponding to the orientation of the respective radial line? (so that for example the 5  on my output would be rotated by 90° counter-clockwise).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A friend of mine once needed kind of a cake to visualize fractions. Adding rotated nodes wasn't hard:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc, fpu, decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\TikZFractionalCake}[5]{% Num, Denom, Color, Borders, Size
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360/#2};%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}%
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lox}{\x-1}%
        \filldraw[draw=#4,fill=#3] (0,0) -- (\angle*\lox:#5) arc (\angle*\lox:\angle*\x:#5) -- cycle;%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mix}{\x-0.5}%
        \node[rotate=\mix*\angle] at (\mix*\angle:#5+0.3) {\x};
    }
}   

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\TikZFractionalCake{20}{20}{white}{black}{3}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Sure, makes it even easier:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc, fpu, decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\TikZFractionalCake}[5]{% Num, Denom, Color, Borders, Size
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360/#2};%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}%
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lox}{\x-1}%
        \filldraw[draw=#4,fill=#3] (0,0) -- (\angle*\lox:#5) arc (\angle*\lox:\angle*\x:#5) -- cycle;%
        \node[rotate=\x*\angle] at (\x*\angle:#5+0.3) {\x};
    }
}   

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\TikZFractionalCake{20}{20}{white}{black}{3}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

That is possible indeed:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc, fpu, decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\TikZFractionalCake}[6]{% Num, Denom, Color, Borders, Size, k-th label
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360/#2};%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}%
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lox}{\x-1}%
        \filldraw[draw=#4,fill=#3] (0,0) -- (\angle*\lox:#5) arc (\angle*\lox:\angle*\x:#5) -- cycle;%
    }
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondstep}{2*#6}
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,int detect,precision=2}
    \foreach \x in {#6,\secondstep,...,#1}%
    {   \node[rotate=\x*\angle] at (\x*\angle:#5+0.3) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\x}};
    }
}   

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\TikZFractionalCake{21}{21}{white}{black}{3}{3} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Is it possible to have the numbers in extension of the radial lines as in Werners first image?

Comment: Thanks. Is it also possible to label only every second or more generally every k'th point?

Comment: Hmm, probably none of the `tikzlibraries` are actually needed, this is due to copy and paste from an old project.

Answer (score 12):

As a typical counterpart to [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pfg) drawings, here's a take on the [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) version.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node
\usepackage{multido}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multido
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(10,10)
  \SpecialCoor
  \psset{unit=3cm,runit=3cm}% Scaling of x,y and r units
  \pnode(3,0){O}% Circle origin
  \pscircle(O){1}% Outer circle
  \degrees[20]% 20 angles per 360 degrees (each angle is 18 degrees)
  \rput(O){\multido{\i=1+1}{20}{% Cycle through 20 angles and relocate relative to circle origin
    \pcline(O)(1;\i)% Print line from origin to circle edge
    \uput{5pt}[\i]{\i}(1;\i){\i}% Print label with rotation
  }}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Modifying the label command to

```
\uput{5pt}[\i]{0}(1;\i){\i}% Print label without rotation
```

yields

[image]

Printing labels at for every *odd* index is possible by using

```
\ifodd\i\uput{5pt}[\i]{\i}(1;\i){\i}\fi% Print ODD label with rotation
```

while

```
\ifodd\i\else\uput{5pt}[\i]{\i}(1;\i){\i}\fi% Print EVEN label with rotation
```

prints only even indices. Here's an illustration of the latter (print *EVEN* labels *with* rotation) choice:

[image]

This can be combined with *no* rotation of every node as well. For this modify the appropriate parameter in the `\uput` command, which is defined by

```
\uput{<labelsep>}[<refangle>]{<rotation>}(<coordinate>){<stuff>}
```

This rotates `<stuff>` by angle `<rotation>` at distance `<labelsep>` and angle `<refangle>` from `<coordinate>`. In my example, using `\degrees[<n>]` divides 360 degrees into `<n>` angles. So, it allows you to use these angles (as numbers, where `angle=i*(360/<n>)`). Also, because of `\SpecialCoor`, one can use polar coordinates - represented by `(<r>;<t>)` - *or* Cartesian coordinates - represented by `(<x>,<y>)`. [`pst-node`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node) allows for substituting any of these `<coordinate>` types with a node `<name>` defined by (say) `\psnode(<coordinate>){<name>}`, as was done in the MWE.

Comment: Thanks. Is it also possible to label only every second point?

Comment: @user4011: I've updated my answer to reflect the possibility to label every other point (even or odd). Other expansions based on similar conditioning is also possible.

Answer (score 5):

You have several solutions :

1) you can mix tkz-euclide with tikz

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDrawCircle[R](O,3 cm)
\def\sectors{20}
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,\sectors} {
    \tkzDefPoint({\i*360/\sectors}:3){P\i}    
    \tkzDrawSegment[color=black](O,P\i)
      \node[label=18*\i:\i] at  (P\i) {} ;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\end{document}
```

3) you use only tikz ! (see Tom' solution)

4) I forgot this one ( I have some difficulties to work with my personal packages).
I put like you `scale=3` but when it's possible I avoid the use of `scale`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDrawCircle[R](O,1 cm)
\def\sectors{20} 
\tikzset{label style/.style={} }; 
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,\sectors} {
    \tkzDefPoint({\i*360/\sectors}:1){P\i} 
    \tkzDrawSegment[color=black](O,P\i)
      \tkzLabelPoint[label=360/\sectors*\i:\i](P\i){}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

5) It's possible to place the label on the radius but I think it's not a good typographic idea

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDrawCircle[R](O,1 cm)
\def\sectors{20} 
\tikzset{label style/.style={} }; 
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,\sectors} {
    \tkzDefPoint({\i*360/\sectors}:1){P\i} 
    \tkzDrawSegment[color=black](O,P\i)
} 
% it's possible to avoid the next loop with conditional macro ...
\foreach \i in {1,3,...,\sectors} {% you can change what you want here
            \tkzLabelPoint[rotate=18*\i,right](P\i){\i} ;
}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better is `  \node[label=360/\sectors*\i:\i] at  (P\i) {} ;   `

Comment: In your first solution the some positions are fine, others are not so good, for example 7 is good, 11 is not so good. Is it possible to fine-control the radial position of the labels?

Comment: @user4011 Yes with the first solution or with the last one (5). You can do what you want with `label=`and it's possible to add an option : `tkzLabelPoint`is like `\node` with only a default style. The second solution is a bad one because I forgot how to remove the default style `above=-6t` is ugly !

Comment: @user4011 Sloped labels are not a good idea. It's more difficult to read and to analyse graph like this. There are some confusions like 6 and 9