# Circle with labelled rotated radians

Tags: diagrams, rotating, labels, circles

I'm wondering how I can reproduce the following diagrams using TeX:

[image: An angle θ with two concentric circles.]

[image: Angles are fractions of a full circle.]

I realize this question is similar to [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32067/label-points-in-a-circle-in-tikz), however I'm not nearly experienced enough to be able to translate from the answer to that question to the above diagram.  (Label rotation, explicit set of rotations, nested circles with partial radians, etc.)

Thank you for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: E.g. in _TikZ_ you can use polar coordinates, like `\node at (30:1) {$\frac{1}{12}$}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility using polar coordinates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
\foreach \mangle/\value in {0/{$0,1$},30/$\dfrac{1}{12}$,45/$\dfrac{1}{8}$,60/$\dfrac{1}{6}$,90/$\dfrac{1}{4}$,120/$\dfrac{1}{3}$,180/$\dfrac{1}{2}$,270/$\dfrac{3}{4}$}
{
  \draw (0,0) -- (\mangle:3.5cm);
  \node at (\mangle:4) {\value};
}
\begin{scope}[yshift=8cm,>=latex]
\draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
\draw (0,0) circle (1.7cm);
\draw[-] (0,0) -- +(60:3.5cm) ;
\draw[-] (0,0) -- +(30:3.5cm) ;
\draw[->] (0,0) -- node[pos=0.95,left=3pt ] {$r_2$} +(60:3cm) ;
\draw[->] (0,0) -- node[pos=0.6,right=6pt] {$r_1$} +(30:1.7cm) ;
\node at (45:3.3) {$s_2$};
\node at (45:2) {$s_1$};
\node at (45:1) {$\theta$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  Now I'll dig through whatever documentation I can find to try to understand all of that.  ^_^

Comment: @GothAlice there's the [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf); the [minimal introduction to TikZ](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf). Search for key terms: `polar coordinates`, `\foreach`.