# circle diagrams text included

Tags: graphics

I wonder how can I draw in graphics in latex

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376573/36296

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117479/circle-with-labelled-rotated-radians

Comment: Please do provide some code to start with. You've got an answer to this, but in general it is better to help others help you by at least coming up with some first ideas. There are plenty of examples on the internet and on this site for any kind of diagrams. As there are different ways to draw diagrams in (La)TeX, it is always good to show some first code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procrastination mode at full power...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5,>=latex,font=\scriptsize]
\draw[thick](0,0)circle(1);
\draw(0,1.5)node[above]{$+Q$ (var)}--(0,-1.5)node[below]{$-Q$ (var)} ;
\draw(-1.5,0)node[above]{$-P$ (W)}node[below]{(Input)}--(1.5,0)node[above]{$+P$ (W)}node[below]{(Output)};
\draw[thick,->](0,0)--node[fill=white]{(Capacitive)}(45:1)node[above right]{$S$ (VA)};
\node at (135:.5){(Capacitive)};
\node at (-45:.5){(Inductive)};
\node at (-135:.5){(Inductive)};
\fill(1,0)circle(1pt)node[below left,fill=white,outer sep=4pt]{Rated $P$};
\fill(0,1)circle(1pt)node[above,fill=white,outer sep=4pt]{Rated $Q$};
\fill(-1,0)circle(1pt) (0,-1)circle(1pt) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5,>=latex,font=\scriptsize]
\draw[thick,gray,dashed](45:1)arc(45:135:1) (225:1)arc(225:315:1);
\draw[thick](-45:1)arc(-45:45:1)--(135:1)arc(135:225:1)--cycle;
\draw(0,1.5)node[above]{$+Q$ (var)}--(0,-1.5)node[below]{$-Q$ (var)} ;
\draw(-1.5,0)node[above]{$-P$ (W)}node[below]{(Input)}--(1.5,0)node[above]{$+P$ (W)}node[below]{(Output)};
\draw[thick,->](0,0)--node[fill=white]{(Capacitive)}(45:1)node[above right]{$S$ (VA)};
\node at (135:.5){(Capacitive)};
\node at (-45:.5){(Inductive)};
\node at (-135:.5){(Inductive)};
\fill(1,0)circle(1pt)node[below left,fill=white,outer sep=4pt]{Rated $P$};
\fill(0,1)circle(1pt)node[above,fill=white,outer sep=4pt]{Rated $Q$};
\fill(-1,0)circle(1pt) (0,-1)circle(1pt) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot