# Illustrating partition of a set on a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles, node-connections

I am writing an essay about partitions of a set. I would like to illustrate partitions on a circle. In order to do that i would like to draw a circle, mark points on it and connect some of them with a line. The desire output would look like this:
[image]

In my essay I will have a lot of examples so I would like to know how to do it with any amount of points and how to draw any line that connects points on a circle. I think that tikz package would be useful.
I know how to draw circle, points and lines using tikz, but i cant get my head around about how to connect this things.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462727/labeling-points-on-a-circle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possibility is to do a marco that draws the set (the circle) and the points, and that names each one. Then all you have to do is connect the desired points. It could be something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Macro
\def\r{2} % raduis
\newcommand{\myset}[4] % name, position x, position y, number of points
{%
  \begin{scope}[shift={(#2,#3)}]
    \coordinate (#1) at (0,0) {};
    \draw (0,0) circle (\r);
    \pgfmathsetmacro\angle{360/#4}
    \foreach\i in {1,...,#4}
    {%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\thisangle{-\angle*(\i-1)+90-0.5*\angle}
      \coordinate (#1-\i) at (\thisangle:\r);
      \node at (\thisangle:1.1*\r) {$\i$};
      \fill (\thisangle:\r) circle (1pt);  
    }
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap=round]
  % A set with 8 points
  \myset{S1}{0}{0}{8}
  \draw (S1-1) -- (S1-3) -- (S1-8) -- cycle;
  \draw (S1-5) -- (S1-7);
  % Anotehr set with 10 points
  \myset{S2}{5}{0}{10}
  \draw (S2-2) -- (S2-5) -- (S2-7) -- (S2-9) -- cycle;
  \draw (S2-6) -- (S2-8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I propose this short code  based on the  `pst-poly` pstricks package:

```
\documentclass[x11names, border = 3pt]{standalone}%
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{pst-poly}
\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)%
\psset{unit = 1.25}
\pscircle(0,0){1}
    \providecommand{\PstPolygonNode}{%
        \psdots[dotstyle=o, dotsize=2pt,fillstyle = solid, fillcolor=IndianRed3](1;\INode)}
    \psset{ linewidth = 0.6pt}
    \rput(0,0){\PstOctogon[linestyle = none, PolyName=A, PolyRotation=45]}
    \psset{nodesep=1pt, linecolor=LightSteelBlue3}
    \ncline{A2}{A3}\ncline{A3}{A8}\ncline{A8}{A2}
    \ncline{A4}{A6}
    \psset{labelsep=3pt}
\multido{\i=3+1,\Id=8 + -1, \na=112.5+45}{6}{\nput{\na}{A\i}{\scriptsize\Id}}
\nput{22.5}{A1}{\scriptsize2}\nput{67.5}{A2}{\scriptsize1}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]